# Viewing updates of a dynamically generated log on a remote linux server from a windows machine

Tags: linux, logging, winscp

I have connected my windows 7 machine via winscp sftp with a cubietruck that runs on debian jessie server.
I need to watch on windows the updated log of an installed app in the linux server.
With winscp I can see this log file. I set the winscp to refresh the remote panel every 10 seconds. I tried to open this log with the following editors:
1) Sublime text with autorefresh plugin
2) Notepad ++ with update silently set
3) Glogg
Unfortunately even though the remote panel was refreshed and watched the log file to grow in size, the file opened in the editors was not updated.
I also tried to set Keep Local Directory up To Date , which creates a replicate file in a local directory in windows. When I had this file opened with the above editors and the remote log file changed then a new file was created on the local disk, without succeeding in watching the updated log.
Does anyone know any solution to this issue or a working alternative ?

Comment: it would be easy with `ssh` access between machines. From Windows, `ssh user@linux.name`. Now `tail -f /path/to/logfile/of_interest.txt`. However, getting `ssh` access can take some time or may not be possible, depending on your security environment. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [klogg](https://klogg.filimonov.dev). It is a fork of glogg. Glogg opens files in such a way that may prevent other programs from accessing them, that is described [here](https://github.com/nickbnf/glogg/issues/109). That has been fixed in klogg(see the [issue](https://github.com/variar/klogg/issues/36) for details).